# How to make ffmpeg.exe solve the inconsistent fps for input frame sequence?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, aforge

We are now using ffmpeg.exe to convert image sequence from IPCAM to output H.264 video in C#. Here, we set the fps of output video for ffmpeg.exe as 10 frames. However, the fps of image sequence from IPCAM is not fixed. Sometime, it is more than 10fps, sometime it is less than 10fps. Because of that, the recorded video length is not exact one hour if we use ffmpeg.exe to record the data during one hour. Could you please let us know which parameters or command of ffmpeg.exe can make ffmpeg.exe solve this inconsistency automatically. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two commands:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s WxH -pix_fmt rgb24 -i \\.\pipe\" + pipename -vsync 0 -r 10 -an -b:v bitrate -vcodec h264_qsv -preset veryslow filename.mkv


ffmpeg.exe -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s WxH -pix_fmt rgb24 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i \\.\pipe\" + pipename -vsync 0 -r 10 -an -b:v bitrate -vcodec h264_qsv -preset veryslow -fflags +genpts filename.mkv
```

Don't change to extension to MP4. If either of the above work, we can then mux the MKV to MP4.

```
ffmpeg.exe file.mkv -c copy file.mp4
```

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, Many thanks for your help. we will try it.